# OpenCL NDRange dimensions order bug on nVidia?

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I know OpenCL is fairly idle these days - especially NVidia's CUDA implementation.  That said I think I've found a significant bug in Nvidia and I'd like to see if anybody else notices the same.  Using Linux   **Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 10.1.0 with C++ bindings**  I've been having all kinds of issues with NDRange order and I finally have a simple kernel that can definitively reproduce the issue:

```
void kernel test()
{
    printf("G0:%d   G1:%d   G2:%d   L0:%d   L1:%d   L2:%d\n", 
    get_global_id(0),
    get_global_id(1),
    get_global_id(2),
    get_local_id(0),
    get_local_id(1),
    get_local_id(2));
}
```

If I enqueue this kernel with 3 dimensions: global (4,3,2) and local (1,1,1):

```
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, 
                cl::NDRange(4, 3, 2), 
                cl::NDRange(1, 1, 1), 
                NULL, events);
```

it randomly outputs the following correctly on AMD/Intel (random output sorted for clarity):

```
G0:0   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:0   G1:1   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:0   G1:1   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:0   G1:2   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:0   G1:2   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:1   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:1   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:2   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:2   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:1   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:1   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:2   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:2   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:1   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:1   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:2   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:2   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
```

This follows the spec.  But if I schedule the exact same kernel with same dimensions using NVidia I the following output:

```
G0:0   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0
```

It seems like NVidia's interpretation of global/local dimensions is interleaved which doesn't match spec.  This doesn't seem to involve the C++ bindings either.  Local ID should never be anything but zero and get_global_id(1) is always zero.

I know NVidia doesn't care much for OpenCL but this seems like a fairly major issue.  Anyone else encounter something like this?  This isn't a synch issue with printf. I've noticed it in actual data use cases and built this kernel only to demonstrate it.

Comment: Correction: this IS a synchronization issue with printf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Although it's hard to verify this in detail, I'll post it as an answer, because from my observations, it *seems* to explain the issue:</sup>

**tl;dr**: The reason is almost certainly due to the lack of synchronization in `printf`.

---

First of all, I observed the same behavior as you: On AMD the output seems to be right. On NVIDIA, it seems to be irritatingly wrong. So I was curious, and extended the kernel, to also print the `get_local_size`:

```
void kernel test()
{
    printf("G0:%d   G1:%d   G2:%d   L0:%d   L1:%d   L2:%d  S0:%d  S1:%d  S2:%d\n", 
        get_global_id(0),
        get_global_id(1),
        get_global_id(2),
        get_local_id(0),
        get_local_id(1),
        get_local_id(2),
        get_local_size(0),
        get_local_size(1),
        get_local_size(2));
}
```

Now, the `get_local_id` certainly **must** be smaller than the size, otherwise most kernels would just crash. On AMD, the output was nice and clean:

```
platform AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
device Spectre
G0:0   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:1   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:2   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:3   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:0   G1:1   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:1   G1:1   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:2   G1:1   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:3   G1:1   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:0   G1:2   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:1   G1:2   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:2   G1:2   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:3   G1:2   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:0   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:1   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:2   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:3   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:0   G1:1   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:1   G1:1   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:2   G1:1   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:3   G1:1   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:0   G1:2   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:1   G1:2   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:2   G1:2   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
G0:3   G1:2   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:1  S1:1  S2:1
```

On NVIDIA, the output was

```
platform NVIDIA CUDA
device GeForce GTX 970
G0:3   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:3   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:0   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:0   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:2   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:2   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:1   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
G0:1   G1:0   G2:0   L0:0   L1:1   L2:0  S0:0  S1:0  S2:0
```

Now, that **cannot** be right: The local work size is always 0!

After some further tests (e.g. with 2D kernels and different numbers), the output *generally* did not seem to make any sense, at all. So I tried this kernel:

```
void kernel test()
{
    printf("G0:%d\n", get_global_id(0));
    printf("G1:%d\n", get_global_id(1));
    printf("G2:%d\n", get_global_id(2));
    printf("L0:%d\n", get_local_id(0));
    printf("L1:%d\n", get_local_id(1));
    printf("L2:%d\n", get_local_id(2));
    printf("S0:%d\n", get_local_size(0));
    printf("S1:%d\n", get_local_size(1));
    printf("S2:%d\n", get_local_size(2));
}
```

The on NVIDIA, the output then is

```
platform NVIDIA CUDA
device GeForce GTX 970
G0:1
G0:1
G0:1
G0:2
G0:2
G0:2
G0:2
G0:2
G0:3
G0:2
G0:3
G0:3
G0:0
G0:3
G0:3
G0:0
G0:0
G0:3
G0:0
G0:0
G0:0
G0:1
G0:1
G0:1
G1:2
G1:2
G1:0
G1:0
G1:1
G1:2
G1:2
G1:1
G1:1
G1:1
G1:0
G1:0
G1:2
G1:1
G1:0
G1:0
G1:2
G1:1
G1:1
G1:0
G1:2
G1:2
G1:0
G1:1
G2:0
G2:0
G2:1
G2:1
G2:0
G2:0
G2:1
G2:0
G2:0
G2:0
G2:0
G2:0
G2:1
G2:1
G2:0
G2:1
G2:1
G2:1
G2:1
G2:0
G2:1
G2:0
G2:1
G2:1
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L0:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L2:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L1:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
S0:1
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
L2:0
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S1:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S1:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S0:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S2:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S2:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S1:1
S2:1
S1:1
S1:1
S2:1
S2:1
S1:1
S1:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
S2:1
```

The key point is: **Each individual** output is **correct**!. The problem seems to be that putting everything into a single `printf` messes up some internal buffer.

This is a pity, of course. It basically makes it impossible to use `printf` for the only purpose that it could sensibly be used for inside a kernel, namely for *debugging*...

---

An aside: The specifications remain a bit hard to interpret at that point - at least when it comes to deciding whether the observed behavior is "right" or "wrong". From the [Khronos documentation of `printf`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/printfFunction.html) :

> In the case that printf is executed from multiple work-items concurrently, there is no guarantee of ordering with respect to written data. For example, it is valid for the output of a work-item with a global id (0,0,1) to appear intermixed with the output of a work-item with a global id (0,0,4) and so on.

The [NVIDIA documentation of the CUDA `printf` implementation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations) also contains some disclaimers and talks about some buffers that may be overwritten, but mapping this (on the technical level of a specification) to the OpenCL behavior is difficult...

Comment: Super helpful thanks for reproducing.  I will give this a try myself in a bit to verify.

Comment: Yes you're right. I thought I reproduced this behaviour without printf but my test itself wasn't accurate.  You are correct on the synch.  Thanks!